# Are these linked server queries susceptible to SQL injection?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, information-schema, sql-injection

I'm using a stored procedure to generate a create table script on the fly based on parameters passed into it. I am validating that the server exists, and then validating if the table exists in the database on said server.

So, first I check if the server exists:

```
Exists(SELECT 1 FROM sys.servers WHERE name = @Server)
```

If it passes this check I go on to build a string that points to `Information_schema`:

```
set @InformationSchemaPath = @Server + '.' + @DataBaseName + '.' +  'information_schema'
```

and then use that string in a dynamic SQL statement that gets put into a string:

```
set @DynamicSQL = ('SELECT count(*) 
             FROM ' +  @InformationSchemaPath + '.Tables
             WHERE  TABLE_NAME = ''' + @TableName + '''')
```

The results get inserted into a temp table:

```
INSERT INTO @receiver Exec (@DynamicSQL )
```

I am unable to use [SP_EXECUTESQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). I am stuck using [Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is unsafe. Try passing this:

```
@TableName = 'FakeTableName'';DROP TABLE Foo;PRINT''You have been Pwned'
```

One way to avoid this is to pass `@TableName` as a parameter to the dynamic SQL. Like so:

```
SET @DynamicSQL = '... WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName'
```

And then do this:

```
INSERT INTO @Receiver EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, @TableName
```

From the wording of your question, I am not sure if you are saying that you can't run `sp_executesql` or that you are not sure about the syntax. If you have to run the statement using only `EXEC` there is a method that works, but only on a Linked Server. You do do this:

```
SET @DynamicSQL = '... WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?'
```

Followed by this:

```
INSERT INTO @Receiver EXEC (@DynamicSQL, @TableName) AT YourLinkedServer
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is still vulnerable.  The @DatabaseName parameter can include code that terminates one command and starts another.  You are creating a string based on @DatabaseName and then executing it.  That is a classic SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I neglected to include that that statement is wrapped in the `Exist` statement. Does this effect running more than one command?

Comment: I am not positive, but I would think that given enough effort a malicious person could abuse it.  I will run some tests.